# Compilation issue ( cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-ip" )

Tags: python, unix, compilation

I'm having trouble while compiling certain python modules. The setup fails with the following error:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-ip"
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I am on a shared system and do not have root access. So, I install the modules using:

```
easy_install --prefix=$HOME/local <module_dir>
```

I looked this up on google and SO but have found no concrete solution yet. From what I understand, it has to do something with the compiler settings/configuration.

I would really appreciate if you could guide me through the steps required to resolve this. I have encountered the same issue with several python modules(pygame, crypto, etc) while most others installed without any hiccups.

Thank You!

Comment: What happens when you do "man cc1", does it have the manual of cc1?

Comment: No manual entry for cc1 found. However, I ran locate and it came back with:

`locate cc1
/usr/lib/bcc/bcc-cc1
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/cc1
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6/cc1plus
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/cc1
/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.1/cc1plus`

Comment: What happens when you run cc1 --version?

Comment: Well, this is strange. It complains that cc1 was not found.
`-bash: cc1: command not found`

Comment: I added the path to cc1 in my PATH variable and retried the setup. However, it exits with the same error. Now, `cc1 --version` returns:

`cc1 --version
GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52).
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=10000
`

Comment: Not sure what to say, if you run "cc1 --prefix=..." what does it give you back/